# Microsoft Test Management, running manual tests in a predefined lab environment

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, manual-testing

I would like some comments on the possibility or alternatives to the following workflow.

**The players:**

- JimBob - Tester
- APP_Test - Virtual machine configured with Lab, Build and Test agent. (shows testing and workflow capabilities active in the environment viewer)
- Manual Test Environment - Environment consisting of one virtual machine "APP_Test"
- Functional Tests - A test plan configured with the Test Environment for Manual runs being "Manual test Environment"
- Build-Deploy - A TFS Build definition that restores a clean checkpoint and then deploys the latest version of the software to the "APP_Test" virtual machine
- Build-Deploy-Test - A TFS Build definition that restores a clean checkpoint and then deploys the latest version of the software to the "APP_Test" virtual machine and then runs coded ui tests contained in the solution.
- John - Tester/Dev

**The scenario:**

JimBob uses the TFS web interface to queue a new workflow build of the software ("Build-Deploy"). As part of the build the latest release of the software is deployed to the virtual machine "APP_Test". JimBob opens Microsoft Test Manager 2010 navigates to the Testing Centre, chooses the Test tab and highlights a Test from a previously defined Test Suite in the test plan "Functional Tests". When JimBob Runs the test the environment viewer opens viewing the "APP_Test" virtual machine. Jim performs the test and creates an action recording on the "APP_Test" virtual machine.

John then takes the action recording and creates a coded ui test, adds the test to the solution and when he queues the "Build-Deploy-Test" build it runs the coded ui test in the same environment that the original action recording was created in.

**Questions:**

I have created the environments, VM, Test plan and Test Suites outlined in the above scenario. What I can't seem to get working is that when a manual test is run it always runs the test on the Local machine not in a VM environment. This will not give me the ability to deploy so that my environment is always in a known state with no interference. I guess my question boils down to: Is it possible to use test management to create action recordings on virtual machines that belong to an environment? I have had success running tests on machines in environments but not making the initial recording. It seems to me that my testers should be able to always perform their tests (automated and manual) in a snapshotted known environment. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do action recording on a remote machine in the environment, see [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsmantest/thread/f11a10d9-b554-4dd3-bbab-c9f4687bed0a)

Instead I installed MTM on the VM so I have a clean environment to build my tests in.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand well, but since you want to perform recording you are talking about CodedUI I guess. I believe that the tester can record in his own workstation and perform any tweaks needed in the code and then deliver you an automated test case. Then you can run this automated test case in any virtual environment that satisfies your preconditions.